# Representing relationship between "Repotee" class and "Manager" class

Tags: object, uml, aggregation, composition, ooad

I am trying to understand the relationship between classes. For example I am trying to understand the relationship between "Manager" class and (his) "Reportee" class, as in below diagram:[image]

To my understanding, "Manager" and "Reportee" can exists independent of each other, and it can't be represented using "inheritance" or "aggreggation" or "composition" (because they can't contain each other, if my understanding is correct".

So how can we code this class relationship?

Any explanation would be of great help.

Comment: Are you after coding or business analysis?

Comment: I am Java developer, so after coding. However want to know the things which  I have been ignoring for a while, and these stuff seem to be abstract. Instead of having doubts, decided to clear them.

Answer (score 1):

Your class diagram is more about business analysis. But then it lacks the direction to which the `reports` shall go. So it's simply incomplete/wrong.

When this model is transformed to something valid for a developer it will need the class methods which implement the report transmission (e.g. there could be a `receive(Report)` method on the `Manager` class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. Agreed that this is incomplete/wrong (because things aren't clear to me :) ). Now about translating into code, does it mean One object would be part of another (for example, Reportee object embedded into Manager Object), if so, isn't that "container-ship" (and in container-ship, we say "has a" relationship. So how come "has a" would become "report". I have difficult in understand this (primarily because my basics aren't clear). Any pointers to get this clear would be of great help.

Comment: No. They are independent classes. Think how they work together. As suggested there might be a method "receive" in `Manager` which accepts a report from the `Reportee`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation. Any good material can your suggest for a novice? Doing google give lots of information,and getting confused what is genuine or not. And BTW, would this kind of study fall under "Software Engineering"?

Comment: Yes, SE is a wide range (I studied it 30 years ago). Look out for ICONIX. This helped me a lot to grasp the basic ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I think above example can explained like following -

Reportee -- Reports to ----> Manager.

This is how we can show association between reportee and manager.You are correct that it is not inheritance, aggregation, composition but it is unidirection association between them.

Link name Reports To give better understanding of relationship between two objects/entities.